# JOOQ SQL given 1 parameters but expected 0

Tags: java, sql, spring-jdbc, named-parameters, jooq

I'm trying to figure out how to use JOOQ with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. I have successfully created other queries, but I'm stuck at creating a query containing the WHERE clause. When I try to run the method below, I get the error **org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: SQL [select "first_name" from "customer" where "id" = cast(? as integer)]: given 1 parameters but expected 0**

I get the same error when I try to use only integers in equals(), like... .where(fieldByName("id").equal(1001), same error and .where(fieldByName("id").equal(id), same error.

If I remove the WHERE clause, the query itself seems to work fine.

What am I doing wrong here? It seems to me that the SQL syntax is correct. It's probably me being stupid, but I really can't find what's wrong here. Please help!

```
public String getCustomerFirstName(int id) {
    Query query = create.select(fieldByName("first_name"))
                    .from(tableByName("customer"))
                    .where(fieldByName("id").equal(param("id", id)));
    Param param = query.getParam("id");
    SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource(param.getName(), id);
    return this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(query.getSQL(), namedParameters, String.class);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have jOOQ generate named parameters, you have to explicitly tell it to do so.

In your case, this would make

```
String sql = create.renderNamedParams(query);
```

The above would replace your call to

```
query.getSQL();
```

Note, this is documented here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/bind-values/named-parameters

A future version of jOOQ (probably 3.1) will probably support initialising your `DSLContext` with a setting to always render named parameters as such. This is registered as a feature request on the roadmap:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2414

Comment: Awesome! I actually read the "Named Parameters" part of the tutorial, but apparently I misunderstood the concept of the renderNamedParams() method in particular. My bad. Everything works fine and dandy now! Thank you, Lukas!

Comment: @Roger: Yes it may be a bit confusing. Named parameters are currently rendered explicitly by this method, as jOOQ couldn't execute the query, otherwise (via JDBC). As a matter of fact, I don't have too much experience with Spring Data and its named parameter support. If you see some potential for API optimisation in jOOQ (e.g. easier extraction of SQL and parameter name/value mapping), feel free to direct a feature request on the user group.